# Formvalidator check even if value is empty

Tags: php, regex, validation

Thanks to this forum I came across below `form validator` some time back which work fine. However, I just have one problem.

When submitting a form with an empty textarea for instance it return the empty field as an error. However, as the value is not mandatory I need to correct this somehow.

```
<?php
/**
* Pork Formvalidator. validates fields by regexes and can sanatize them.         Uses PHP       filter_var built-in functions and extra regexes 
* @package pork
*/


/**
* Pork.FormValidator
* Validates arrays or properties by setting up simple arrays
* 
* @package pork
* @author SchizoDuckie
* @copyright SchizoDuckie 2009
* @version 1.0
* @access public
*/
class FormValidator
{
public static $regexes = Array(
        'date' => "^[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{1,2}[-/][0-9]{1,2}\$",
        'datetime' => "20\d{2}(-|\/)((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))(-|\/)((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))(T|\s)(([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-3])):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])",
        'amount' => "^[-]?[0-9]+\$",
        'number' => "^[-]?[0-9,]+\$",
        'alfanum' => "^[0-9a-zA-Z ,.-_\\s\?\!]+\$",
        'not_empty' => "[a-z0-9A-Z]+",
        'words' => "^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z \\s]*\$",
        'phone' => "^[0-9]{10,11}\$",
        'zipcode' => "^[1-9][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]{2}\$",
        'plate' => "^([0-9a-zA-Z]{2}[-]){2}[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}\$",
        'price' => "^[0-9.,]*(([.,][-])|([.,][0-9]{2}))?\$",
        '2digitopt' => "^\d+(\,\d{2})?\$",
        '2digitforce' => "^\d+\,\d\d\$",
        'anything' => "^[\d\D]{1,}\$",
        'username' => "^[\w]{3,32}\$"
);

private $validations, $sanatations, $mandatories, $equal, $errors, $corrects, $fields;


public function __construct($validations=array(), $mandatories = array(), $sanatations = array(), $equal=array())
{
$this->validations = $validations;
$this->sanatations = $sanatations;
$this->mandatories = $mandatories;
$this->equal = $equal;
$this->errors = array();
$this->corrects = array();
}

/**
* Validates an array of items (if needed) and returns true or false
*
* JP modofied this function so that it checks fields even if they are not submitted.
* for example the original code did not check for a mandatory field if it was not submitted.
* Also the types of non mandatory fields were not checked.
*/
public function validate($items)
{
$this->fields = $items;
$havefailures = false;

//Check for mandatories
foreach($this->mandatories as $key=>$val)
{
    if(!array_key_exists($val,$items))
    {
        $havefailures = true;
        $this->addError($val);
    }
}

//Check for equal fields
foreach($this->equal as $key=>$val)
{
    //check that the equals field exists
    if(!array_key_exists($key,$items))
    {
        $havefailures = true;
        $this->addError($val);
    }

    //check that the field it's supposed to equal exists
    if(!array_key_exists($val,$items))
    {
        $havefailures = true;
        $this->addError($val);
    }

    //Check that the two fields are equal
    if($items[$key] != $items[$val])
    {
        $havefailures = true;
        $this->addError($key);
    }
}

foreach($this->validations as $key=>$val)
{
        //An empty value or one that is not in the list of validations or one that is not in our list of mandatories
        if(!array_key_exists($key,$items)) 
        {
                $this->addError($key, $val);
                continue;
        }

        $result = self::validateItem($items[$key], $val);

        if($result === false) {
                $havefailures = true;
                $this->addError($key, $val);
        }
        else
        {
                $this->corrects[] = $key;
        }
}

return(!$havefailures);
}

/* JP
* Returns a JSON encoded array containing the names of fields with errors and those without.
 */
public function getJSON() {

$errors = array();

$correct = array();

if(!empty($this->errors))
{            
    foreach($this->errors as $key=>$val) { $errors[$key] = $val; }            
}

if(!empty($this->corrects))
{
    foreach($this->corrects as $key=>$val) { $correct[$key] = $val; }                
}

$output = array('errors' => $errors, 'correct' => $correct);

return json_encode($output);
}



/**
 *
 * Sanatizes an array of items according to the $this->sanatations
 * sanatations will be standard of type string, but can also be specified.
 * For ease of use, this syntax is accepted:
 * $sanatations = array('fieldname', 'otherfieldname'=>'float');
*/
public function sanatize($items)
{
foreach($items as $key=>$val)
{
        if(array_search($key, $this->sanatations) === false && !array_key_exists($key, $this->sanatations)) continue;
        $items[$key] = self::sanatizeItem($val, $this->validations[$key]);
}
return($items);
}


/**
 *
 * Adds an error to the errors array.
 */ 
private function addError($field, $type='string')
{
$this->errors[$field] = $type;
}

/**
 *
 * Sanatize a single var according to $type.
 * Allows for static calling to allow simple sanatization
 */
public static function sanatizeItem($var, $type)
{
$flags = NULL;
switch($type)
{
        case 'url':
                $filter = FILTER_SANITIZE_URL;
        break;
        case 'int':
                $filter = FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT;
        break;
        case 'float':
                $filter = FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT;
                $flags = FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION | FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND;
        break;
        case 'email':
                $var = substr($var, 0, 254);
                $filter = FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL;
        break;
        case 'string':
        default:
                $filter = FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING;
                $flags = FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES;
        break;

}
$output = filter_var($var, $filter, $flags);            
return($output);
}

/** 
 *
 * Validates a single var according to $type.
 * Allows for static calling to allow simple validation.
 *
 */
public static function validateItem($var, $type)
{
if(array_key_exists($type, self::$regexes))
{
        $returnval =  filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=> array("regexp"=>'!'.self::$regexes[$type].'!i'))) !== false;
        return($returnval);
}
$filter = false;
switch($type)
{
        case 'email':
                $var = substr($var, 0, 254);
                $filter = FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL;        
        break;
        case 'int':
                $filter = FILTER_VALIDATE_INT;
        break;
        case 'boolean':
                $filter = FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN;
        break;
        case 'ip':
                $filter = FILTER_VALIDATE_IP;
        break;
        case 'url':
                $filter = FILTER_VALIDATE_URL;
        break;
}
return ($filter === false) ? false : filter_var($var, $filter) !== false ? true :     false;
}           
}
?>
```

So from what I understand I need to come up with a a way to validate an empty string as the above code will throw an error.

```
$validations = array(
    'id' => 'number', //Value in _POST['id'] = '11'
    'time' => 'datetime', //Value in _POST['time'] = '2016-03-17T11:05:01'
    'description' => 'anything'); //Value in _POST['decription']  = '' 

$required = array('id', 'time');

$validator = new FormValidator($validations, $required);

$validator->validate($_POST);
print_r $validator->getJSON();
```

Comment: `filter_var($var, $filter) !== false ? true : false` => I love your style :)

Comment: @Thomas: At least, it's `true` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should either make the field required and add something like this

```
// validation
    if (empty($variable)) {
        echo 'such&such is required<br />';
        $ok = false;
    }
```

Or make the variable `=""` or `null;`

Comment: Added this and still same error: `'description' => strlen($_POST["description"]) ? '' : $_POST["action_description"],` same if I use `empty`

Comment: Yes, when setting a value to `description` their is no error. However when setting no value in `textarea` error is thrown even if I use `'description' => empty($_POST["description"]) ? '' : $_POST["action_description"],`

Comment: As far as I understand I need to change something within the class